# Sequencial loop in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array of objects and I'm trying to perform an operation using data from every object.

I'm using a loop to go through all the objects, and inside the loop I have another loop that is supposed to perform an operation as many times as a number in the object property.

Here's my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.clusters.length; i++) {
  if ($scope.clusters[i].latitude && $scope.clusters[i].longitude){
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.clusters[i].numberpatients; i++) {
      var heat = [$scope.clusters[i].latitude,$scope.clusters[i].longitude];
      $scope.resultsheat.push(heat);
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that for each object in `cluster`, `var heat` gets pushed into `$scope.resultsheat` as many times as the `numberpatients` variable.

For example, if in an object's `numberpatients` is 15, it should get pushed 15 times.

In the code above I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'numberpatients' of undefined
at main.js:99
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I suggest you use different index variables, you have `var i` for both loops

Comment: Before using property, check if object has that property using hasOwnProperty.

Comment: What happens if you change the index variable of your inner loop?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey that fixed. If u add as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Curious case of closure!